# Javascript for loop error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have:

```
function get_bad_changelist_authors() {
   var changelistAuthorDivs = $('div.bad_changelist_author');
   var changelistAuthors = [];

   for (var div in changelistAuthorDivs) {
      changelistAuthors.push($(changelistAuthorDivs[div]).text());
   }

   return changelistAuthors;
}
```

changeListAuthorDivs has n elements but for some reason it iterates n+1 times and initialized div to a string (ie. the string "length") on the last iteration. On the last iteration is where this loop has its error.

Comment: Already tried using a for loop with an explicit indexer? Like for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)

Comment: Why not [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)?

Comment: lol, i was just seriously confused about how div ="length...i find that a strange concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript `for...in` loops will also iterate over properties of the object (`length` is a property of the object, which is why you end up with a `div` containing that string), which is not what you want. Use a normal `for` loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < changeListAuthorDivs.length; i++) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using jQuery *(please confirm)*. Then you can use [`.map()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to achieve the same in a more concise way:

```
function get_bad_changelist_authors() {
   return $('div.bad_changelist_author').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
   }).get();
}
```

Alternatively , use [`.each()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) if you deal with jQuery objects.

In general, @James is completely right, don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays ([see the warning here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description)). In this case, the jQuery object has to be treated like an array.

Comment: Sweet, I think I'll try the map function out. And thanks for pointing out a resource where I can checkup Javascript documentation.

Comment: @Nadir: You are welcome. The jQuery documentation and the Mozilla JavaScript reference and guide are really great. I suggest to read the guide, it will give you some more insight into JavaScript. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for (var div in changelistAuthorDivs) {
     if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(changelistAuthorDivs[div], div))
     changelistAuthors.push($(changelistAuthorDivs[div]).text());
  }
```